# decoding two different base64 strings returns two times the same string

Tags: encoding, debian, base64, basic-authentication, dyndns

base64 encoding / decoding uses deterministic algorithms. Because of that, a given input string will be always encoded to a known output string and vice versa.

Using the browser to access a URL secured with basic authentication, the browser encodes the username:password pair to a base64 string and places that string into the HTTP Authorization request header. Using Firebug it is easy to read that encoded string from the network monitor - let's call it string A.

On a raspberry (running Debian Wheezy) I installed the ddclient to update dns records for my domain using dyndns. The ddclient configuration is provided with the same username:password pair as used to access the URL with a browser. The client even tries to access the same URL (using basic authentication) but the access fails because of a bad authentication. Within the ddclient's debug output I can read the base64 encoded string - let's call it String B.

For any reason String A and String B are different! But they are created from the same username:password pair. If I decode the strings in the Debian shell

```
echo myBase64EncodedStringGoesHere | base64 --decode
```

or in the browser console using JavaScript

```
atob('myBase64EncodedStringGoesHere')
```

the result is always the same username:password pair, no matter if I decode String A or String B.

My only explanation is that there are maybe some non-visible control characters in the username:password configuration of the ddclient, influencing the base64 encoding result. Thus I checked the ddclient configuration using the `vi` editor with command

```
:set list
```

It looks all good. I am stumped. Does anybody has a glue what's going?

### Update 1

because of @C4stor's comment I checked what happens when I take my username:password pair and encode it with the shell command

```
echo username:password | base64
```

As result I get String A with padding chars `==` at the end. Besides from the padding the debian OS created the same string as the web browser (used on Windows) does.

### Update 2

As requested by @umläute, here are two demo strings:

`Stirng A: bXlkb21haW4uY29tOmRueURucz
String B: bXlkb21haW4uY29tOmR5bkRucz`

decoding them in the browser console using

```
atob('STRING')
```

gives always the same decoded string.

Comment: There's 14 variants of Base64 decoding and encoding referenced by the wikipedia. Would it be possible your raspberry and your Firebug aren't using the same ?

Comment: well, good point. I checked it. I update the question with the results of the checks.

Comment: couldn't you try to provide the *actual* base64 encoded strings in the question? (just configure your system to use a non-existing username/password to not disclose your secrets)

Comment: sure, see update 2 on the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does conversion from two different base64 strings return equal arrays of bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850390/why-does-conversion-from-two-different-base64-strings-return-equal-arrays-of-byt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the ddclient's config file there must have been some non-visible control characters, maybe due to a copy & paste...

Using `vi` I deleted the content from the file and wrote each line manually by hand. Now the ddclient produces the expected base64 encoded string.

I still wonder why I wasn't able to see the characters with vi's `:set list` command, but at least now the problem is solved.